# Нахождение наиболее часто используемой первой буквы в файле со словами

Tags: python, словари

Задача заключается в том, что дан набор слов и частоты встречаемости этих слов в тексте. Необходимо найти самую часто встречаемую букву среди всех. Работа с файлом.
Пример содержимого файла:

```
    "10 абрикос
    8 сингулярность
    3 пирамида"
    list1 = []
    list3 = []
    list2 = []
    list4 = []
    c = 0
    Max = 0
    dictionary = dict()
    d1 = []
    f = open("1.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
    a = f.readlines()
    for i in a:
        b = i.split(" ")
        for j in b:
            list1.append(j)
    list1 = [line.rstrip() for line in list1]
    print(list1)
    for i in range(0, len(list1)):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            for j in list1[i]:
                list2.append(j[0])
                break
        elif i % 2 == 0:
            list3.append(list1[i])
    for i in list3:
        i = int(i)
        list4.append(i)
    dictionary = {i : j for i, j in zip(list4, list2)}
    d1 = sorted(dictionary)
    print(d1)
    for i in range(0, len(d1)):
        if d1[i - 1] == d1[i]:
            c = c + d1
            if c > Max:
                Max = c
            print(d1[i], Max)
```

Comment: так что все-таки надо найти _"наиболее часто используемой первой буквы"_ или _"самую часто встречаемую букву среди всех"_?

Answer (score 1):

Можно так сделать:

```
file = open('file.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='r') # открываем файл
letters_freq = dict()
for line in file: # перебираем строки в файле
    count, word = line.rstrip().split(' ')
    count = int(count)
    for letter in word: # считаем количество каждой буквы
        try:
            letters_freq[letter] += 1
        except KeyError:
            letters_freq[letter] = 1
file.close() # закрываем файл
values = sorted(letters_freq.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print(f'{values[0][0]} встречается {values[0][1]} раз. Частота: {values[0][1] / sum(letters_freq.values())}')
```

Comment: А саму частоту как вывести?

Comment: @hidwidwi  изменил вывод.

Answer (score 1):

Похожий вариант, но с использованием `Counter`. Как он работает читайте [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
with open('friq.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for l in f:
        n, s = l.strip().split()
        c += Counter(s * int(n))

print(c)
'''
Counter({'с': 26, 'и': 24, 'р': 21, 'о': 18, 'а': 16, 'н': 16, 'б': 10, 'к': 10,
         'г': 8, 'у': 8, 'л': 8, 'я': 8, 'т': 8, 'ь': 8, 'п': 3, 'м': 3, 'д': 3})
'''

print('"{}" встречается {} раз'.format(*(c.most_common(1)[0])))
'''
"с" встречается 26 раз
```

**PS**

> дан набор слов и частоты встречаемости этих слов в тексте

видимо, частота встречаемости слов дана в условии не просто так

Comment: В итоге моя мысля пришла к этому, выше ответ

Comment: @hidwidwi, не уверен, что ваш код работает правильно. Вот это `list2.append(j[0])` зачем?

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = []
list3 = []
list2 = []
list4 = []
c = 0
letter = []

f = open("words_freq1.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
a = f.readlines()

for i in a:
    b = i.split(" ")
    for j in b:
        list1.append(j)
list1 = [line.rstrip() for line in list1]

for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    if i % 2 != 0:
        for j in list1[i]:
            list2.append(j[0])
            break
    elif i % 2 == 0:
        list3.append(list1[i])

for i in list3:
    i = int(i)
    list4.append(i)

for i in range(0, len(list2)):
    if list2[i] == list2[0]:
        c = c + list4[i]
        letter.append(list2[i])

print(letter[0], c)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]